# expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token

Tags: c++

I might just be blind, but I can't seem to find anything wrong with this code. I am running 2 dc motors off of a L298N h-bridge and am simply trying to change their direction.

I keep getting this error: sketch_mar23a.ino:61:1: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token

Here is the code:

```
//Motor A

int enA = 9;
int in1 = 8;
int in2 = 7;

//Motor B

int enB = 3;
int in3 = 5;
int in4 = 4;

void setup()
{

  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT); 
}

void demoOne()
{
  //runs bopth motors

  //motor A
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);

  //set speed
  analogWrite(enA, 200);

  //motor B
  digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);

  //set speed
  analogWrite(enB, 200);

  delay(2000);

  //change direction
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);

  delay(2000);

  //turn motors off
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
}


void loop();
{
  demoOne();

  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: Compare `void loop(); {` with e.g. `void demoOne() {`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`void loop();` should be `void loop()`. Remove the `;`.